# JFrame not becoming transparent

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Recently I have been trying to get a transparent JFrame without success.

I want to make all components visible but not the frame and I see that people set the background to transparent and set Opaque to false.

I am doing this but without success.

```
public class KeyDialog extends JFrame {
    public static MapPanel mapPanel = new MapPanel();

    public KeyDialog() {
        GridBagConstraints customGridBagLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setUndecorated(true);
        // Title - Row 1
        JTextField row1 = new JTextField();
        row1.setSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), HEIGHT));
        row1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        PromptSupport.setPrompt("Title Goes Here", row1);
        customGridBagLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 0;
        add(row1, customGridBagLayout);

        // Key - Row 2
        JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
        row2.setOpaque(false);
        // With Key
        JPanel withKey = titleBoxKey(true);
        withKey.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        row2.add(withKey);
        // Against Key
        JPanel againstKey = titleBoxKey(false);
        againstKey.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        row2.add(againstKey);

        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 1;
        add(row2, customGridBagLayout);

        pack();
    }

    public static JPanel titleBoxKey(boolean with) {
        JPanel keyPanel = new JPanel();
        keyPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints customGridBagLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
        customGridBagLayout.insets = new Insets(7, 7, 7, 7); // Padding
        Color republicanColor = null;
        Color democraticColor = null;
        if (with) {
            republicanColor = mapPanel.getRepublicanWithColor();
            democraticColor = mapPanel.getRepublicanAgainstColor();
        } else if (!with) {
            republicanColor = mapPanel.getDemocraticAgainstColor();
            democraticColor = mapPanel.getDemocraticAgainstColor();
        }

        // Row 1 - Rectangles and Text Field
        // Democratic Rectangle
        JLabel republicanRect = mapPanel.drawRect(republicanColor);
        customGridBagLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        customGridBagLayout.weightx = 0.5;
        customGridBagLayout.gridx = 0;
        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 0;
        keyPanel.add(republicanRect, customGridBagLayout);

        // Republican Rectangle
        JLabel democraticRect = mapPanel.drawRect(democraticColor);
        customGridBagLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        customGridBagLayout.weightx = 0.5;
        customGridBagLayout.gridx = 1;
        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 0;
        keyPanel.add(democraticRect, customGridBagLayout);

        // With/Against Label
        JLabel infoLabel;
        if (with) {
            infoLabel = new JLabel("With");
        } else {
            infoLabel = new JLabel("Against");
        }
        customGridBagLayout.weightx = 0.5;
        customGridBagLayout.gridx = 2;
        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 0;
        keyPanel.add(infoLabel, customGridBagLayout);

        // Row 2 - Bottom Text
        // Republican Label
        JLabel republicanLabel = new JLabel("Republican");
        customGridBagLayout.weightx = 0.5;
        customGridBagLayout.gridx = 0;
        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 1;
        keyPanel.add(republicanLabel, customGridBagLayout);

        // Democrat Label
        JLabel democraticLabel = new JLabel("Democratic");
        customGridBagLayout.weightx = 0.5;
        customGridBagLayout.gridx = 1;
        customGridBagLayout.gridy = 1;
        keyPanel.add(democraticLabel, customGridBagLayout);

        return keyPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `if (with) {/*...*/} else if (!with) {/*...*/}` >> in the else part, `with` is by definition false. No need to check `if(!with)` there. In this case just write `if (with) {/*...*/} else {/*...*/}`.

Comment: Thanks TT, will change

Comment: I have no experience with this, but I'm guessing your content pane is opaque (`JFrame.getContentPane` / `JFrame.setContentPane`).

Comment: @TT can you please elaborate on your point, thanks

Comment: Each JFrame has a content pane. That is the container that stores all the components that are displayed on the frame. The components in the content pane are layed out on the screen using the layout manager. If you add a component to a frame using `JFrame.add` they are added to the content pane container. You can find this information also in the [`JFrame` class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and more details in the [Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) documentation.

Comment: In that last link, you will read: *The default content pane is a simple intermediate container that inherits from `JComponent`, and that uses a BorderLayout as its layout manager*. So if that content pane is opaque, it doesn't matter that you add components to it that aren't. Your frame won't become transparant as long as the content pane is opaque. That's what I know about the architecture and my analysis of why your frame won't become transparant as long as you don't make the content pane transparant.

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe set the layered pane transparant. As I said, no experience making a frame transparant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the background to `frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` thanks to the help of @JontyMorris

I then set all the contents on the frame to opaque `panel.setOpaque(false);`
and removed the backgrounds I set so the stripped down version looks like this...

```
// Frame
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // Setting frame to be transparent

// Components
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//add stuff to panel...
panel.setOpaque(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a nice attempt, but try this instead.

```
// Apply a transparent colour
setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
```

Simply add that code and your done :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a bit more to it than setting the background color. You have to change the undecorated property to true. Here's a quick tutorial you can follow. Well explained.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zecGJfNHPWo

Comment: This can be a comment. Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.